# Python Pandas - Merge DataFrame, preserve index

Tags: python, merge, pandas

What I'm trying to do is basically to merge two `DataFrame` objects in Pandas while preserving the index (`DateTimeIndex`). Neither the `merge` or `ordered_merge` support this.
Presuming I have stock data constructed like so:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
aapl_old = DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', datetime(2013,1,1), datetime(2013,3,1))
aapl_new = DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', datetime(2013,2,1), datetime(2013,4,1))
```

How would I go about getting one final merged `DataFrame` with the indexes intact?

What I've tried so far (and doesn't work):

- Any sort of `merge` operation - so far as I can tell, simply doesn't support preserving indexes on many-to-many data
- A few variations on index slicing:

  ```
  aapl_new.ix[aapl_new.ix > aapl_old.ix[-1]]
  aapl_new.ix[aapl_new.ix > aapl_old.ix[-1].name]
  ```

How I think I might be able to solve this:

- A different version of index slicing - am I approaching this the wrong way?
- A `reset_index()` and `reindex()` operation - having a lot of trouble with the `reindex()` part.
- Finding indexes unique to `aapl_new` and `append`ing those to `aapl_old` - no idea how to find which rows in `aapl_new` don't appear in `aapl_old`

Please let me know if there's any more information I need to supply.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "merge"?  Do you simply want to concatenate the DataFrames?

Comment: By "merge" I do mean to [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) like in the documentation. The problem was when I would do a merge operation, pandas would destroy the index, meaning that I lost the DateTime the data came from. Does this clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are asking (but this is not very clear), I think you want the following.

First, to merge the two dataframes you can simply concatenate the two using `concat([aapl_old, aapl_new])` (this will preserve the index). But to remove the duplicates you can think of two strategies:

1) You can only concat those from `aapl_new` that are unique (do not appear in aapl_old). To select those, you can do:

```
aapl_new[~aapl_new.index.isin(aapl_old.index)]
```

And this you can then concat with aapl_old:

```
>>> aapl_new_unique = aapl_new[~aapl_new.index.isin(aapl_old.index)]
>>> pd.concat([aapl_old, aapl_new_unique])
```

2) You could also just concat the dataframes, and then remove the duplicate rows:

```
>>> aapl_all = pd.concat([aapl_old, aapl_new])
>>> aapl_all.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create the first dataframe
- df.append(new_dataframe) # assuming the structure is correct

You could then use the drop_duplicates() method to remove dupes if they exist.